# Pass C++ jintArray to C# function

Tags: c#, java, c++, arrays, java-native-interface

i have C# dll which has a function

```
public static Int32[] remDup(Int32[] dArray){
   return dArray.Distinct().toArray();
}
```

i have jni function for this

```
JNIEXPORT remDup..... ( jintArray dupArray){
    // from java call i get dupArray
    CsharpDLL::CSharpClass::remDup(/*pass an int32 array */)
}
```

i have java function which calls below function using jni

```
  remDup (Int[] array)
```

i m calling C# DLL from Java using C++ wrapper... i have already spent half of the day to find out to pass jIntArray to C# dll function ... but no success.. with complete R&D as much as i can doo..

differet techniques

i.e  `array<System::Int32^)^ array, Marshal techniques` but still unable to pass array from C++ (JintArray) to C# DLL .. plz help or guide

Comment: This may help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtbydz1t.aspx

Comment: @Bogdan thnx dude! BUT its giving following **ERROR** a value of type `"cli::array<int,1>^"` cannot be used to initialize an entity of type `"cli::array<System::Int32^,1>^ "`

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with jintArray, but worst case solution is to create a new cli::array<int> of the size of your jintArray and then use a for to set all elements to the new array and pass that to c# function ...

Comment: @Bogdan thanx dude, your link was helpful to me ... if you can properly answer above comment as answer.. i can marked it as answer :)

Comment: Added as answer, I do not chase points but some may search that question on google and it will be useful to them ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to create a new cli::array of the size of your jintArray and then use a for to set all elements to the new array and pass that to c# function.